# Why do I get an error "cannot be used as a function"?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
float getBalance ();
float quarterOne (float bb1);


int main (void)
{
    float bb1;
    bb1 = getBalance();
}

float getBalance ()
{
    float bb;   
    
    printf("Beginning Balance: ");
    scanf("%f", &bb);   
    
    return bb;
}   

float quarterOne (float bb1)
{
    float Q1;
    Q1 = bb1(1+((5.3/100)*0.25)); // there comes the error
    printf("\t1st Quarter Balance: %.2f",Q1);
    
}
```

It says my variable `bb1` cannot be used as a function. Why? Is there an alternative so that I can pass my `bb` value from the `getBalance` function to the `quarterOne`?

Comment: `Q1=bb1(1+...` ==> `Q1=bb1*(1+...`

Comment: BTW: always prefer `double` when dealing with floating-point values. Forget `float` (and `long double`) exists.

Comment: @pmg I'm not sure the OP is ready for the concept of pointers, let alone function pointers

Comment: You are asking two questions. Please decide on one.

Answer (score 3):

Using a symbol with an open parenthesis, like `bb1(...)`, tells the compiler that you are trying to use it as a function

bb1 is not a function though, you probably want to multiply the value of it by

`(1+((5.3/100)*0.25))`

You just forgot to put `*` between `bb1` and the parentheses.

```c
Q1 = bb1 * (1+((5.3/100)*0.25));
```

Comment: You only answer one of the two questions. But there should only be one and I agree that you chose the one which can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
...
int main (void)
{
    float bb1;
    bb1 = getBalance();
    printf("\t1st Quarter Balance: %.2f", quarterOne(bb1));
}
...
float quarterOne (float bb1)
{
    return bb1 * (1 + ((5.3 / 100) * 0.25));    
}
```